# How to use array optimization in boost serialization

Tags: c++, optimization, boost-serialization

I have to serialize an object that contains a `std::vector<unsigned char>` that can contain thousand of members, with that vector sizes the serialization doesn't scale well.

According with the documentation, Boost provides a [wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#arrays) class array that wraps the vector for optimizations but it generates the same xml output. Diving in boost code, i've found a class named `use_array_optimization` that seems to control the optimization but is somehow deactivated by default. i've also tried to override the serialize function with no results.

I would like to know how to activate that optimizations since the documents at boost are unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER() macro and coded two functions for loading and saving. The Save function looks like:

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
std::string     sdata;
Vector2String(vData, sdata);
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("vData", sdata);
}
```

The Vector2String function simply takes the data in vector and format it to a std::string. The load function uses a function that reverses the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the array optimization is that, for arrays of types that can be archived by simply "dumping" their representation as-is to the archive, "dumping" the whole array at once is faster than "dumping" one element after the other.

I understand from your question that you are using the xml archive. The array optimization does not apply in that case because the serialization of the elements implies a transformation anyway.

Comment: I try to serialize the whole vector<unsigned char> instead of each item. Now i get something like

<data><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>170</item><item>255</item>....

I need something like

<data>0102AAFF</data>

(notice the hexa encoding)

I think that there has to be a solution in boost or at least some way to override the default behavior.

Comment: @jab, xML can do that encoding for you, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to serialize a `vector` with Boost Serialization to XML.
From what I read in the comments your are looking for Case 2 below.

I think you cannot change how `std::vector` is serialized by library after including `boost/serialization/vector.hpp`, however you can replace the code there by your own and by something close to Case 2.

### 0. Library default, not optimized

The first is to use the default given by the library, that as far as I know won't optimize anything:

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
...
    std::vector<double> vec(4);
    std::iota(begin(vec), end(vec), 0);

    std::ofstream ofs{"default.xml", boost::archive::no_header};
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive xoa{ofs};
    xoa<< BOOST_NVP(vec);
```

output:

```xml
<vec>
        <count>4</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item>0.00000000000000000e+00</item>
        <item>1.00000000000000000e+00</item>
        <item>2.00000000000000000e+00</item>
        <item>3.00000000000000000e+00</item>
</vec>
```

### 1. Manually, use that data is contiguous

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/array_wrapper.hpp>  // for make_array
...
        std::ofstream ofs{"array.xml"};
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive xoa{ofs, boost::archive::no_header};
        auto const size = vec.size();
        xoa<< BOOST_NVP(size) << boost::serialization::make_nvp("data", boost::serialization::make_array(vec.data(), vec.size()));
```

output:

```xml
<size>4</size>
<data>
        <item>0.00000000000000000e+00</item>
        <item>1.00000000000000000e+00</item>
        <item>2.00000000000000000e+00</item>
        <item>3.00000000000000000e+00</item>
</data>
```

### 2. Manually, use that data is binary and contiguous

```cpp
#include <boost/serialization/binary_object.hpp>
...
        std::ofstream ofs{"binary.xml"};
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive xoa{ofs, boost::archive::no_header};
        auto const size = vec.size();
        xoa<< BOOST_NVP(size) << boost::serialization::make_nvp("binary_data", boost::serialization::make_binary_object(vec.data(), vec.size()*sizeof(double)));
```

```xml
<size>4</size>
<binary_data>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAACEA=
</binary_data>
```

I think this makes the XML technically not portable.